# How to get json values for a key using javascript or jquery or angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have the following json:

```
var jsonobj = {
    "title" : "Testing",
    "settings" : {
    "mysettings" : false
    },
    "jsonlist": ["TestingList"],
    "testjsonvals": {
        "Test1": {
            "name": "name1",
            "description": "Test1 description"
            },
        "Test2": {
            "name": "name2",
            "description": "Test2 description"      
        },
        "Test3": {
            "name": "name3",
            "description": "Test3 description"            
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get/show description values of Test1, Test2, Test3 only from my given json on one alert message(like: `Test1 description, Test2 description, Test3 description` should show on my alert message) either using javascript or jquery or angularjs ?  Please help me and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should iterate `jsonobj["testjsonvals"]` (or `jsonobj.testjsonvals`) object keys and concatenate `description` values, or  push them into array and `join()`

```js
var jsonobj = {
    "title" : "Testing",
    "settings" : {
    "mysettings" : false
    },
    "jsonlist": ["TestingList"],
    "testjsonvals": {
        "Test1": {
            "name": "name1",
            "description": "Test1 description"
            },
        "Test2": {
            "name": "name2",
            "description": "Test2 description"      
        },
        "Test3": {
            "name": "name3",
            "description": "Test3 description"            
        }
    }
}


var msg = [];
$.each(jsonobj["testjsonvals"], function(key,v){ msg.push(v["description"]) });
alert(msg.join(", "));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
var tests=jsonobj['testjsonvals'];
alert(tests["Test1"]['description'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var message = jsonobj.testjsonvals.Test1.description + ', ' +
    jsonobj.testjsonvals.Test2.description + ', ' +
    jsonobj.testjsonvals.Test3.description;
alert(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert( jsonobj ['testjsonvals'['Test1'].description,  + 
       jsonobj ['testjsonvals'] ['Test2'].description,  + 
       jsonobj ['testjsonvals']['Test3'].description );
```

or

```
alert( jsonobj.testjsonvals.Test1.description, + 
       jsonobj.testjsonvals.Test2.description,  + 
       jsonobj.testjsonvals.Test3.description );
```

Let me know if this code helped you

Answer (score 1):

This will loop over all your testjsonvals and add them to an array that we join together with space and alert

```
var arr = [];
for(i in jsonobj.testjsonvals)
{
    arr.push(jsonobj.testjsonvals[i].description);
}

alert(arr.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you iterate through `jsonobj.testjsonvals` you should be able to build up your string to match what you require. Something like this should do the trick:

```
var jsonobj = {
    "title" : "Testing",
    "settings" : {
    "mysettings" : false
    },
    "jsonlist": ["TestingList"],
    "testjsonvals": {
        "Test1": {
            "name": "name1",
            "description": "Test1 description"
            },
        "Test2": {
            "name": "name2",
            "description": "Test2 description"      
        },
        "Test3": {
            "name": "name3",
            "description": "Test3 description"            
        }
    }
};

var tests = jsonobj.testjsonvals;
var msg = [];
for (var i in tests) {
  if (tests.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    msg.push(tests[i].description);
  }
}
alert(msg.join(' '));
```